# How to reduce an array of numbers with similar values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to create a method that takes a list of numbers and can reduce the array by a supplied variance.

**Variance Explained:**

The variance should match a value below and above. So for example, the variance of 100 equated against the value: 5460 should match any value between 5410 - 5510. (50 below the equated value and 50 above)

For instance if I have the array:

```
[ 1576420754, 1576420756, 1576593554, 1581172759, 1581172764 ]
```

I want to created a method **filterSimilarValues(array, variance = 100)**

Which would give me the following output:

```
[ 1576420756, 1576593554, 1581172764 ]
```

I have tried a couple things, like

```
const filterSimalarValues = (array, variance = 100) => {
    let filteredArray = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        const number = array[i];

        if (number >= number - (variance / 2) && number <= number + (variance / 2)) {
            return;
        }

        filteredArray.push(number);
    }

    return filteredArray;
};
```

Comment: please share how did you try to solve this and what is your issue?

Comment: this is an algorithm problem, how should your `variance` work?

Comment: If there is a commonly used interpretation of "variance" in the context you use it, i do not know it.

Comment: When you have the values : [10,12,13,14,15,16] and a variance of 5, what is supposed to be the output? [10,16] or for example [13]?

Comment: I have added an explanation of the variance, hope that helps. Apologises for the vagueness previously.

Comment: No, sadly, it does not help. Your example shows a "variance" of 100, while your desired result array has values which vary by the tens of millions. What value should values be compared to in the first place?

Comment: How are the groupings defined? If it's a variance of 100, is it 0 -99, 100-199? so 99 and 100 should go in different groups? Or is it "If this number is within 100 of a number that's already in the array, don't add it, otherwise add it"?

Comment: The first two values in the original array are different by just 2 (1576420754, 1576420756) and the last two are different by 5 (1581172759, 1581172764) so I want to just have one value for those similar ones. Like treating them as duplicates.

Comment: That's a start, but which value should be chosen of the ones that are "too close", and what if there is e.g. the example that Joost commented above?

Comment: You "would want [10, 16]", but why, what's the reasoning, so it can be reproduced for any array?

Comment: In that case I would want [13] actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Array.filter()` to retain only numbers that the absolute difference (`Math.abs()`) between the them and the next number is greater or equal `variance / 2`. The last item (`i === array.length - 1`) is included by default.

```js
const filterSimalarValues = (array, variance = 100) => 
  array.filter((n, i) => 
    i === array.length - 1 ||
    Math.abs(n - array[i + 1]) >= variance / 2
  )

const data = [1576420754, 1576420756, 1576593554, 1581172759, 1581172764]

const result = filterSimalarValues(data)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I've updated the handling of the last item (`i === array.length - 1`), since using `array[i + 1] || Infinity` would give wrong results if the `array[i + 1]` is 0.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like:

```
const filterSimalarValues = (array, variance = 100) =>
  array.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const variant = acc.find(
      item => curr > item - variance / 2 && curr < item + variance / 2,
    );
    if (!variant) {
      acc.push(curr);
    } else {
      acc[acc.indexOf(variant)] = curr;
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
```

Also, in my opinion you should be more specific with your question, there are a lot of possible (edge) cases not covered.

Answer (score 0):

As per the explanation provided and my understanding of variance, you want to limit the numbers between the variance range. I am assuming you have a minimum of 2 elements but you can add checks for that case.

```js
const filterSimalarValues = (array, variance = 100) => {
    const filteredArray = [];
    filteredArray.push(array[0]);//bench mark to check
    for (let i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        const number_lower_bound = array[i] - variance/2;
        const number_upper_bound = array[i] + variance/2;
        var bound_exist = false;
        for(var bound = number_lower_bound;bound<=number_upper_bound;bound++){
          if (filteredArray.includes(bound)) {
              bound_exist = true;
              break;
          }
        }
        if(!bound_exist){
            filteredArray.push(array[i])
        }
      }
    }
    return filteredArray;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have come up with, it works, but there might be a better solution so I am not accepting my own answer.

```
const filterSimilarValues = (array, variance = 100) => {
  let filteredArray = [];

  array.forEach(number => {
    const start = number - (variance / 2);
    const end = number + (variance / 2);
    const range = Array(end - start + 1).fill().map((_, idx) => start + idx);
    const found = range.some(r => filteredArray.includes(r))

    if (!found) {
      filteredArray.push(number);
    }
  });

  return filteredArray;
};
```